# How to find only py file names in which target text is present?

Tags: python, linux, shell, centos

I am using `CentOS`
I have to find `/tmp` text in ONLY `.py` files of current directory `/var/opt`

I try following, this is give me all files i.e. `py`, `pyc` and `text` in which `/tmp`  found.

```
$ pwd
/var/opt
$ grep -r "/tmp" * >>/tmp/241_tmp.txt
```

Following is not working:

```
$ grep /tmp *.py 
grep: *.py: No such file or directory
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `--include` parameter:

```
grep -r --include \*.py "/tmp" /var/opt
```

Note that you need to escape the `*` symbols using backslash.

There is also an `--exclude` parameter, you can use it if you need the otherwise - except some files (like `*.pyc`) from the search.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to search .py files, don't search all files:

```
grep /tmp *.py
```

If your current directory is different, specify the path:

```
grep /tmp /var/opt/*.py
```

Comment: `$ grep /tmp *.py 
grep: *.py: No such file or directory`  not wokring

Comment: Then I don't understand what you meant by "of current directory".

Comment: I want all py file names from the `/var/opt` directory location which contains `/tmp` string

Comment: @VivekSable: Do you mean subdirectories recursively as well? If not, my solution should just work. Also, see the update.